# Add a new column that tells me the first date a condition was met over a certain number of consecutive days when I have missing Dates

Tags: r

I have the following sample data:

```
ID=rep(c(1,2,3),times=10)
Date=rep(seq(as.Date("2020-05-16"),as.Date("2020-05-25"),1),each=3)
Dist=c(191,134,607,970,1050,480,302,200,108,420,1050,480,302,200,108,420,191,134,607,970,
       480,302,200,108,560,490,480,302,200,108)
dat<-data.frame(ID=ID,Date=Date,Dist=Dist)

dat<-dat %>% 
  arrange(ID,Date)
dat<-dat[-2,]
dat<-dat[-25,] %>% 
  arrange(ID,Date)
```

I would like to have R loop through my data and look for instances where I have a Dist of less than or equal to 500 for at least three consecutive days. The issues is sometimes I am missing a date in my dataframe. This is probably not the best way to do it, but I have gotten to the point where I have added a column where there is a value of 1 when I have three occurences in  a row where there is a distance <=500, and 0 when this is not the case. Additionally I have added a column where I calculate the difference in Dates between my rows:

```
dat<-dat %>% 
  arrange(ID,Date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(den=ifelse((lag(Dist)<=500)&Dist<=500&lead(Dist)<=500,1,0),
         date_diff=c(0,diff(Date))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Essentially I would like to go through each unique ID (and eventually Year) and add a column corresponding to the first Date where I have three consecutive days of a distance less than or equal to 500 (i.e. the first day where the distance traveled by an animal was less than or equal to 500m for at least three consecutive days). This could occur more than one for an ID or not at all.

In my head I thought I could use the same logic (using lead() and lag()) to look for times where I only have a difference in the Date of 1 through the following logic:

```
dat<-dat %>% 
  mutate(Crit=ifelse(den==1 & (lead(date_diff==1)&date_diff==1&
                                 (lag(date_diff==0)|lag(date_diff==1))),1,0))
```

HOWEVER, the issue with this is what I think the next step would be is to filter for when the new Crit column is =1, however, this is not always the first date in the series that meets these criteria. Is there a way I can just tell R to look for less than 500 in my Dist column over at least 3 consecutive days in my Date column, and then pull that first date into a new column?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could complete the data so you have all Dates for each ID and then just use lags to evaluate the criterion:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
ID=rep(c(1,2,3),times=10)
Date=rep(seq(as.Date("2020-05-16"),as.Date("2020-05-25"),1),each=3)
Dist=c(191,134,607,970,1050,480,302,200,108,420,1050,480,302,200,108,420,191,134,607,970,
       480,302,200,108,560,490,480,302,200,108)
dat<-data.frame(ID=ID,Date=Date,Dist=Dist)

dat<-dat %>% 
  arrange(ID,Date)
dat<-dat[-2,]
dat<-dat[-25,] %>% 
  arrange(ID,Date)

dat %>% 
  complete(ID, Date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(crit = Dist < 500 & lag(Dist) < 500 & lag(Dist, 2) < 500, 
         mindate = min(Date[which(crit)]))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>       ID Date        Dist crit  mindate   
#>    <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <lgl> <date>    
#>  1     1 2020-05-16   191 NA    2020-05-20
#>  2     1 2020-05-17    NA NA    2020-05-20
#>  3     1 2020-05-18   302 NA    2020-05-20
#>  4     1 2020-05-19   420 NA    2020-05-20
#>  5     1 2020-05-20   302 TRUE  2020-05-20
#>  6     1 2020-05-21   420 TRUE  2020-05-20
#>  7     1 2020-05-22   607 FALSE 2020-05-20
#>  8     1 2020-05-23   302 FALSE 2020-05-20
#>  9     1 2020-05-24   560 FALSE 2020-05-20
#> 10     1 2020-05-25   302 FALSE 2020-05-20
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>